# Only complete code in Xcode with Tab, not Enter

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

How can I set Xcode so that only Tab completes code, and not Enter?

Because if I'm typing something and want to move to the next line, then it requires that I hit Esc first to close code completion, then Enter.

Disabling Enter for code completion would certainly save a few keystrokes.

Comment: Did you looked at the settings of Xcode ?

Comment: Hmm? Unless there is a specific preference to change this behavior, it's just the way it is. (I'm assuming you are asking as a *user* and not as one of XCode's IDE programmers.)

Comment: Yes I looked through the settings, and Googled for solutions online, quite thoroughly. And yes I'm asking as a user. I'm not an Apple employee...

Comment: for comparison, the VSCode equivalent is `"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off"`, and it appears as of Dec 2023, this is still not possible in XCode.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like as of Dec 2023, this is still not possible in Xcode.

For comparison, in VSCode the setting would be `"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off"`.

One partial workaround in Xcode to get rid of the annoying "Enter" behavior is to Xcode -> Settings -> Text Editing -> Editing, and then uncheck "suggest completions while typing", and check "Use escape key to show completion suggestions". This doesn't fully solve the original question the way the VSCode setting would, but it at least prevents the annoying Enter key capture.